# PHP star doesn't fill in when user favourites item

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This is a really specific question but I've been stuck on it for a while now. I am creating an application where users can log in and favourite certain courses by clicking on a star icon. I want it to work like on many social networking sites where if you click the star, it fills in to show it has been favourited. It will save the course ID and session Email to the favourite table fine but I cannot get the courses that are favourited to show as a filled in star. The problem bit is `if(($_SESSION["Email"] == $row3["Email"]) && ($row["ID"] == $row3["ID"])){` and so on.

```
<?php session_start(); 
    include "connection.php";
    $sql="SELECT * FROM course";
    $result= mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM course, university WHERE course.UNI_ID = university.UNI_ID";
    $result2 = mysqli_query($con, $sql2);
    $row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM favourite";
    $result3 = mysqli_query($con, $sql3);
    $row3 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result3);

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      echo "<table border='2px' width='100%'><tr><td><b>".$row2["Name"]."</b></td><td><img src= 'images/".$row2["Logo"]."' width='25px'></td></tr><tr><td><b><a href=course.php?ID=".$row["ID"].">".$row["Course_name"]."</b></td><td>".$row["Course_length"]."</td></tr><tr><td width='80%'><a href=course.php?ID=".$row["ID"].">UCAS Requirements: ".$row["UCAS"]."+ ".$row["Subject_requirement"]."<br>Student Rating: <img src=images/".$row["Student_rating"]." width='80px'></td>";       

        if(isset($_SESSION["Email"])) {
            if($_SESSION["Admin"] == "1") {
                echo "<td width='20%'><input type=\"button\" value=\"Delete\" onClick=\"window.location.href='deletecourse.php?=ID".$row["ID"]."'\"><br><br><input type=\"button\" value=\"Edit\" onClick=\"window.location.href='editcourseform.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."'\"></td></tr></table>";
            }
            if($_SESSION["Admin"] != "1") {
                if(($_SESSION["Email"] == $row3["Email"]) && ($row["ID"] == $row3["ID"])) {
                    echo "<td width='20%'><a href=unfavourite.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."><img src=images/favouritefilledin.fw.png width='45px'></td></tr></table>";
                }
                else {
                    echo "<td width='20%'><a href=favourite.php?ID=".$row["ID"]."><img src=images/favourite.fw.png width='45px'></td></tr></table>";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            echo "<td width='20%'><a href=log_in.php><img src=images/favourite.fw.png width='45px'></td></tr></table>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I had to seriously edit the indentation of your nesting.  That might just be a function of posting to SO with the code block, but you should make sure your real code has *pretty* and well *styled* indentation. It will save you lots of grief in the future when dealing with this many levels of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

You're not looping through the favourite results, you need to check them all

1. You need to first create an array of "favourite" courses for that email, so in your MySQL query check for the email too
2. And then rather than

   ```
   ($row["ID"] == $row3["ID"])
   ```

   use

   ```
   in_array($row["ID"],$favouriteCourses)
   ```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to PHP and am wondering how I would create an array of favourite courses from the database?

Comment: So, make an array  $favouriteCourse=array(); and then loop through your favourite courses result and add them to the array $favouriteCourses[] = $row3["ID"]), also you don't want $row3["ID"], you want the course ID in that table which I presume is in another column.